# Adding leading zeroes for multiple columns in dplyr (R)

Tags: r, dplyr, leading-zero

I'm looking to add zeroes to several columns at the same time in R using `dplyr` syntax. (I've come across some similar questions, but none gives me exactly what I want; they're either for single columns or for base syntax.)

I have this:

```
    x   y
1 001  04
2   2 455
3  32   6
```

and I want this:

```
    x   y
1 001 004
2 002 455
3 032 006
```

Here's a solution that I found, but not with `dplyr` and piping

```
# Make data
x <- c("001", "2", "32")
y <- c("04", "455", "6")
X <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

# Define and apply function with lapply
lead_cols <- c("x","y")

lead_zeros <- function(col) {
  sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(col))
  }
X[lead_cols] <- lapply(X[lead_cols], lead_zeros)
```

Here's what I've come up with in `dplyr`, but it doesn't work:

```
X[lead_cols] <- X %>% mutate_at(lead_cols, sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(lead_cols)))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") :
```

object ' NA' of mode 'function' was not found

The solution must be simple, but I've been banging my head against the wall and just want some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a formula or anonymous function in that mutate call. BTW, `mutate_at()` is superseded by `across()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
x <- c("001", "2", "32")
y <- c("04", "455", "6")
X <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

lead_cols <- c("x","y")

X %>% mutate(across(all_of(lead_cols), ~ sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(.x))))
#>     x   y
#> 1 001 004
#> 2 002 455
#> 3 032 006
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip about "across"; I had used it in some versions of my code, but the trick was ".x", the anonymous function. Is there anywhere I can read more about anonymous functions and what they do?  Many thanks! :)

Comment: perhaphs https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts . `~ .x + 1` notation is widespread across tidyverse packages and functions, though they now seem to recommend new(ish) R function shorthand , `\(x) x + 1` , instead - https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html#arguments (.f argument) & `?"function"`  for doc.

Answer (score 2):

We may use `str_pad` from `stringr` - it can pad the character input with leading 0s

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
X %>%
   mutate(across(all_of(lead_cols), str_pad, width = 3, pad = "0"))
```

-output

```
   x   y
1 001 004
2 002 455
3 032 006
```